# Python: difference between `a,b=[1,2],a` and `a=[1,2]; b=a`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In my understanding, the above two pieces of code should have the same effect. But why when I let a point to another array, the results could be different? The following code illustrates the difference:

```py
# part 1
a=[1,2]
b=a
a=a+[3] # a points to a new array. b should still points to [1,2]
print(a, b) # [1, 2, 3] [1, 2]. My expected result.

# part 2
a,b=[1,2],a
a=a+[3] # a points to a new array. b should still points to [1,2]
print(a, b) # [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]. Why the result is different from the above?
```

I'm surprised by the result of the part 2. Could someone please explain why the results are different? Thank you so much in advance!

EDIT: Thank you so much for everyone! Now I understand the problem! Thanks so much!

Comment: The line `a,b=[1,2],a` wouldn't work if "part 1" didn't run first, since there's no `a` to be assigned to `b`. You need the assignment to `a` to complete before assigning to `b` and therefore only "part 1" will ever work for this logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the order of operations.

The expression `[1,2],a` is building a tuple with two elements.  The first element is the list `[1,2]` and the second element is the existing value of `a` which was set in part 1 to `[1,2,3]`.

Now that tuple is unpacked by the assignment, so `a = [1,2]` and `b=[1,2,3]`.

Then you modify `a` so it coincidentally is the same as `b`.

The whole process would have been much clearer if you'd used different constants in the two parts of your test.

```
# a=[1,2,3] from part 1
a,b=[4,5],a
a=a+[6]
print(a,b) # [4, 5, 6] [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to run your tests in isolated environments. Your "part 2" test is grabbing the `a` value from "part 1".

Comment: Exactly. One would get an error on trying to use 'a' that would still be undefined at that point, and instantly realize whats going on.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
a,b=[1,2],a
```

assigns `[1,2]` to `a`, and assigns the previous value of `a` to `b`.

This means `b` will have the previous value of `a`, which is `[1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

Well, `a` was already `[1, 2, 3]` from "part 1" so when you assign that to `b` in "part 2", of course `b` is going to be `[1, 2, 3]`...

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the whole code in a time?
If you are doing this, thhe confusion is easily explained.

When you set b = a in the second part, it takes the actual a value, which is [1,2,3] due to the first part.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are running both part_1 and part_2 at the sametime in the same environment.
Now In this line  `a, b = [1,2], a` List `[1,2]` is being assigned to `a` but the part_1 value of `a` is assigned to `b` which is `[1,2,3]`. Because of this reason, you are getting `[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]` for both `a` and `b`.

Now if you try to run part_2 seperately you will run into a `nameError` because in part_2, `a=[1,2]` and `b=a` are being executed at the sametime. Which means that the `a` is not yet assisned to `[1,2]` when it is being assigned to variable `b`.